# How do I change my apple id country without a credit card?

Tags: itunes, apple-id, gift

Man, what do i do?

This happened I don't have money in the account but my relative gave me some money but it's in USD and I am in India.

When I change my apple id country it says "give billing option".

Comment: So your relative gave you an iTunes gift card?

Comment: Yes my relative gave me a gift card

Comment: Did you try creating a US iTunes account and adding the gift card?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your question is 2 fold:

> 1. Can I accept an iTunes gift card from another country?
> 2. Can I change my apple id country without providing a credit card?

Looks like in both cases it's a **No**.

**1. Can I accept an iTunes gift card from another country?**

## From the [Apple Forums](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4932463?start=0&tstart=0)

> You can't redeem it outside of the USA. You also can't change the
>   iTunes Store country while any of its balance remains.

**2. Can I change my apple id country without providing a credit card?**

For this you can enter a credit card, but it's ***not charged*** unless you purchase an item from iTunes or the App Store.

There appear to be a bunch of different [hacks](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4078601?start=15&tstart=0) around this, but nothing definite from my estimation.